# How can i use a min() funct in this sql query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
UPDATE
            MRT

SET 
             Date = MR.Date

FROM
             MRT
             JOIN MR on MR.SKU = MRT.SKU
```

HERE Is where i would like to do an `order by min(mr.Date)`

All I get is an incorrect Syntax error.

I have to set the date = the smallest mr.date

Comment: I'm not sure this makes sense. Ordering by a field is used for output. You're doing an update, which will modify data but not display any output. Are you trying to specify the order that the update should occur in? That wouldn't make much sense either...

Comment: Why are you trying to ORDER an UPDATE?

Comment: Why does the order matter when you're doing an UPDATE?

Comment: because i have to set one field equal to the smallest date

Comment: I don't understand what you want from the query. Do you only want records with dates after mr.Date?

Comment: no i want the smallest mr.date

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE MRT SET Date = (SELECT min(Date) FROM MR WHERE MR.SKU = MRT.SKU);
```

Comment: No it sets the Date field in each row of MRT to the minimum Date from MR where the SKU fields are the same.

Comment: You need a WHERE clause to select which records need updating